# Is it "me" or "I" in this sentence? And why?

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence:

___, the mastermind, and you, the slave.

Should it be "me" or "I"? And why?

Comment: "Me." Sometimes you will hear that "I" is used in the subjective case, so people will try to slip "I" into all sorts of places on the thought that a subject is needed, but in reality "I" is only for some narrow constructions involving pairing with verbs. In natural English, "me" is what real people use as our first-person singular pronoun in all cases that don't fit the narrow "I" constructions -- "Me and Tina went to the store", "Who did it? Me!", etc.

Comment: You can't actually say, because that's just a fragment, not a sentence; there is no verb and thus no way to tell whether "I/me" and "you" are the subjects or the objects of the verb.

Comment: @Greater The problem with fragments in this context is that key information is missing, so we can't give you a definitive answer. By way of analogy: "Is a t-shirt ok, or do I need to dress up?" You can't answer that definitively without knowing the context.

Comment: @Greater Please add clarification **to the question** (there's an "edit" link under it), rather than bury it in comments. Please give the complete context, not merely "after a series of complete sentences": we need those sentences.

Comment: No, that's not specific enough, because you say "could be", even though you already know the "series of complete sentences". Questions need to be **an actual real-world problem that you face.** And if you see the current answer and my comment on that, you'll see that **exactly** what precedes it is vitally important.

Comment: Please **edit the question,** before it's closed for lack of detail.

Comment: @Hellion Simply not how English really works. People say that "I" is the subjective-case pronoun, but the actual use of "I" is narrower than that. No sensible person would answer "Who?" with "I."

Answer (score 1):

Add a verb and all becomes clear.  "I/me am the mastermind and you (are) the slave."

Comment: This process leads to ridiculous (though sometimes-advocated) constructions like "I am taller than she" rather than "I am taller than her."

Comment: On the other hand, if you add "It is", you get "It is me, the master mind, and you, the slave."

Comment: But if it's the answer to "Who should he give the parcel to?" then it's "Me, the mastermind, and you, the slave" -- while that may not occur very often, it's an indication of why **all** the context is needed in a question.

Comment: @MikeGraham How does this process say anything at all about the case of the noun following "than"?

Comment: @MikeGraham  Would you say, "I am taller than his?"  If not, please explain the difference?

Comment: @BobBrown I would say "I'm taller than his" in a context where that made sense, of course. If I was comparing my height to his height, I would say "I am taller than him" or "I am taller than he is", like all people speaking English as it actually occurs in the wild. No one says "I am taller than he" because that's how English is spoken--they say it because they heard the silly rule in your post and tried to follow it.